# Keep track of function calls in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is there a good way to keep track of called functions in JavaScript? At the moment, the only way I can think of is to keep global array to store functions that are called and within each function append the function name and values of the parameters into the array every time it is called.

For instance

```
var functionCalls = [];
var functionIndex = 0;

function func1(param1, param2, ... , paramN) {
    ...
    functionCalls[functionIndex] = [func1, param1, param2, ..., paramN];
    functionIndex++;
}

function func2(param1, param2, ... , paramN) {
    ...
    functionCalls[functionIndex] = [func2, param1, param2, ..., paramN];
    functionIndex++;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to keep track of function calls? If you're debugging, you should just step through a debugger.

Comment: @zzzzBov Not for debugging, but I wanted to keep track of all functions called and their parameters to re-execute part of the functions with the same parameters again in the same order later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to run some kind of analysis on your code, consider using an external tool/library rather than hard-code it into your application.

[Esprisma's function instrumentation example](http://esprima.org/demo/functiontrace.html) shows the possibility to inject instrumentation at runtime to keep track of function calls and such.

Edit: after reading your comment explaining the intent of this question:

You could create a decorator function that you simply pass an scope, function, arguments, and ID (to call again later).

```
// define some function we can use to call functions with that will save
// previous execution parameters so we can repeat previous calls
callFunction = (function() {
    var called = {};

    function callFunction() {
        // turn the arguments associative array into a real array
        args = Array.prototype.slice(arguments, 0);

        if(args.length == 4) {
            // assume we want to call and save the function
            runAndSaveFunction.apply(this, args);
        }
        if(args.length == 1) {
            // assume we want to recall a function based off an id
            repeatCall.apply(this, args);
        }
    }

    function runAndSaveFunction(context, func, args, id) {
        // call the function given a context
        func.apply(context, args);

        // save the call
        called[id] = {
            fn: func,
            args: args,
            ctx: context
        };
    }

    function repeatCall(id) {
        var call = called[id];
        runAndSaveFunction(call.ctx, call.fn, call.args, id);
    }


    return callFunction;
})();
```

Then we can use this function something like:

```
// this function exists just to call our real function
// below with our instrumentation
function func1() {
    callFunction(this, _func1, arguments, 'someId');
}

// we designate the original as a "private" function that
// actually contains the implementation
function _func1(param1, param2, ... , paramN) {
    ...
}

func1(a, b, c, d, e...);
callFunction('someId'); // recall the previous func1 call
```

Note: There might be syntax/language errors in the code above; it's meant to be used as a guide

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you might be walking down the wrong path but here is a way to do it:

```
Function.prototype.track = function() {
    var fn = this;
    return function() {
        //do tracking here
        console.log(arguments)
        return fn.apply(this, arguments);
    }
}
//You don't have to make it a method on all functions
//I never add to prototypes of native Objects but it
//does look more elegant for this scenario.
```

Example:

```
function sum(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

var sumTracker = sum.track();
var onePlusTwo = sumTracker(1,2)
> [1, 2] 
onePlusTwo
> 3
```